# Getting node's size before the scene is shown

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any way to do so?

I'm thinking of setting pref size in FXML, but I'm not sure if the pref size is always the same as real, shown size of the node.

I don't want to do this after the scene is shown, as I'm looking for more elegant solution. I want to perform some calculations with the node's size, so it would be great to do this before scene showing.

EDIT:

My goal:

I want to set Stage's minimal width and height that depends on a node size (panelVBox + insets ofcourse). This should be done just one time (no binding or something - just the initial size of panelVBox). I just want to prevent the window from being too small. The panelVBox should be always visible.

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<HBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="800.0" spacing="20" fillHeight="false"
      xmlns:fx="gui" fx:id="mainHBox" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="15" left="20" right="20" top="15"/>
    </padding>
    <VBox spacing="20" fx:id="panelVBox">
        <HBox spacing="5">
            <Text text="Amount:"/>
            <Label text="0" fx:id="amountLabel"/>
        </HBox>
        <VBox spacing="10">
            <Text text="To do:"/>
            <TextField fx:id="toDoTextField"/>
            <GridPane>
                <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" percentWidth="45"/>
                    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" percentWidth="10"/>
                    <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" percentWidth="45"/>
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints percentHeight="100"/>
                </rowConstraints>
                <Button maxWidth="Infinity" text="START" GridPane.columnIndex="0" fx:id="startButton"/>
                <Button maxWidth="Infinity" text="STOP" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/>
            </GridPane>
        </VBox>
    </VBox>
    <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" prefHeight="Infinity"/>
</HBox>
```

The only way I can think of is checking the panelVBox size after Stage.show(), but as I said, I don't like this way.

Comment: Node size may change. You may want to use binding to node's size properties. To get better answers try to give more context.

Comment: The more elegant solution is to respond to size changes (i.e. creating a responsive UI). Could you provide a [mre] demonstrating what you're after, please? And also make it clearer what the problem is.

Comment: @Slaw some more description in EDIT

Comment: @Slaw provided some code and description

Comment: `<VBox fx:id="panelVBox" minWidth="300.0" minHeight="200.0" spacing="20">` ?